# eclipse rcp:how to pass selection into handler

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have a view part in my ecp application, it just contains a `TreeViewer`.

each tree node has a action provider which will contribute to the context menu when the node is right clicked:

```
MenuManager menuManager = new MenuManager();
        menuManager.addMenuListener(new IMenuListener(){

            @Override
            public void menuAboutToShow(IMenuManager manager) {
                IStructuredSelection is = (IStructuredSelection)treeViewer.getSelection();
                if(is.isEmpty()){
                    return;
                }else{
                    Node node = (Node)is.getFirstElement();
                    IActionProvider provider  = node.getActionProvider();
                    IContributionItem[] actions = provider.getActions();
                    if(actions.length == 0){
                        return;
                    }else{
                        for(IContributionItem action : actions){
                            manager.add(action);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        });
        Menu menu = menuManager.createContextMenu(treeViewer.getTree());
        menuManager.setRemoveAllWhenShown(true);
        treeViewer.getTree().setMenu(menu);
        getSite().registerContextMenu(menuManager, treeViewer);
        getSite().setSelectionProvider(treeViewer);
```

a action provider example :

```
public class CPSActionProvider implements IActionProvider {
    private Object source;

    @Override
    public void setInitializationData(IConfigurationElement config,
            String propertyName, Object data) throws CoreException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public IContributionItem[] getActions() {
        CommandContributionItemParameter cp = new CommandContributionItemParameter(
                PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow(),
                null, "cn.ggfan.dmp.commands.addCP",
                CommandContributionItem.STYLE_CHECK);
        HashMap<String, Object> paras = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        paras.put("source", this.source);
        cp.parameters = paras;
        CommandContributionItem add = new CommandContributionItem(cp);
        //add.setId("cn.ggfan.dmp.commands.addCP");
        return new IContributionItem[] { add };
    }

    @Override
    public void setSource(Object o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.source = o;
    }

}
```

`cn.ggfan.dmp.commands.addCP` is a defined command which has a `defaultHandler`, the source field is the node being right clicked, now my question is how to pass the source field into the handler? As you can see, I am trying to do it like this:

```
HashMap<String, Object> paras = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        paras.put("source", this.source);
        cp.parameters = paras;
```

but it does't work.

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to set your `Tree/Table Viewer` as `SelectionProvider` to `PartSite`.

IWorkbenchSite.java

```
 public void setSelectionProvider(ISelectionProvider provider);
```

1. Your command handler code, you have below method

public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException

Use   `ISelection selection = HandlerUtil.getCurrentSelectionChecked(event);`

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

there is another approach if don't workbench provided SourceProvider. You can implement your own

```
org.eclipse.ui.ISourceProvider
```

its your responsibility to update provider Map. Here is sample reference

http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseCommandsAdvanced/article.html

Comment: I know this approach, I am just looking for a better way.

Comment: Updated my answer. I just want to understand what do you mean by better way!